Running AutolabelImg, getting an error at the last step only - error related to Qt platform plugin
(ano) workstation@workstation-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~/AutoLabelImg$ python labelImg.py
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x55c44f0738c0) is not the object's thread (0x55c453f4ba80).
Cannot move to target thread (0x55c44f0738c0)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/workstation/anaconda3/envs/ano/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.
Aborted (core dumped)
Please help with this error -
associated github repo - https://github.com/wufan-tb/AutoLabelImg/issues/new
tried reinstalling qt extensions, not able to do anything which is removing the error, circling back to this error only again and again.
